# PHP - Investigate HTTP content from supplier

Tags: php, http

I have asked a supplier to send my orders (pdfs) via HTTP rather than email delivery but they are unable to tell me what the HTTP query will comprise of.  I know this is bad form, but nonetheless I would like to try to find a solution.  I have provied a php URL for them and it is being called when i place an order, but I am not sure how to scrutinise the call from their server to try to find out what they need.  A the moment they are getting a 500 server error back from me.

This is the code i have.  It is being called and the handle is being updated, but only the date is being posted there nothing else.

```
<?

$handle = fopen("landstore.txt", "w");

if (isset($_POST))  {

fwrite($handle, date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)  {
    fwrite($handle, $key." post =");
    fwrite($handle, $value.",  ");
        }
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}

if (isset($_FILES)) {

fwrite($handle, date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)  {
    fwrite($handle, $key." post =");
    fwrite($handle, $value.",  ");
    }
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}

if (isset($_GET))   {

fwrite($handle, date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)  {
    fwrite($handle, $key." post =");
    fwrite($handle, $value.",  ");
    }
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}

fclose($handle);

?>
```

How can i improve on my code to gather some meaningful results about what they are sending to my server? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend a third-party service called Runscope - https://www.runscope.com/. There's a free tier, and they give you a URL that'll record every POST/GET/etc. request made against it for you to inspect.

I'm unaffiliated but have used them in the past for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Donquick Hope it helps! Unfortunately with a vendor that can't even tell you what their own system will send, it may be a long hard road... :(

Comment: If you need any help troubleshooting, hit us up at help@runscope.com any time!